# Delete rows depending on the fill of a column. Python, Exсel, Win32com

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

Good afternoon, I need the program to delete the entire line if in the B column the fill color is Black. So that only the lines with the gray fill are left.

[image]
I try this:

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook
sheet = wb.ActiveSheet
i = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
while i >= 1:
    if self.Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex == 0:
        self.Rows(i).Delete()
        i += -1
```

But not sure what is right, plus an error:

```
NameError: name 'xlCellTypeLastCell' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to delete cells in an excel worksheet marked by black color, using python?**

Assuming:

- The worksheet is the active worksheet
- Cells are in the second column and are marked by fill of black color
- We don't know how much cells are there in the worksheet

code:

```
import win32com.client as win32client

excel = win32client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
sheet = excel.Application.ActiveSheet
range_ = sheet.Range("B:B")
for cell in range_:
    if cell.Interior.ColorIndex == 1:
        cell.Delete()
```

Comment: This deletes the cell, but it is necessary: if the cell in the B column is black, then all the row is deleted.
The problem is that if I try to delete the entire line, then Excel crashes with an error that it cannot process such a number (although not a lot of lines) or deletes all lines in a row